# Is it worth trying to use SOAP?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, soap, rich-internet-application

I have a small RIA that I built as a learning/make-my-life-easier project that uses Flex and ASP.Net.  Currently, my architecture utilizes straight HTTP posts and the server responds with xml. I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353160/security-for-flex-app-when-ssl-is-not-available) about security in my web app and some people mentioned SOAP.  SOAP is something I've never actually used and I was wondering what the pros/cons were to using SOAP over my current architecture and then subsequently, how much work is require to convert such an application to utilize SOAP.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Seems you're currently using a RESTful web service technique instead of SOAP. ;-) See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Comment: Indeed it would appear that way, good call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already implemented your own message schemas for sending and receiving, then SOAP in of itself will not give you any added value. The added value comes from SOAP's support for the WS-* standards, covering security, transactions, and several other goodies. The recommended way to take advantage of all that is to use WCF rather than ASP.NET, because WCF supports the latest versions of those standards.

Comment: Flex doesn't support most of those WS standards.

Answer (score 1):

FYI when trying to use SOAP with FLEX - XMLDecoder in Flex does not currently decode some complex data types appropriately, making it appear that you are not receiving all data. I have tracked the error down to the XMLDecoder where I can see the correct data is received, but is not appropriately packaged in the ResultEvent requiring me to override the XMLDecoder, which, I am sure you can imagine, is not very fun. Just wanted to put in my 2 cents.  If you are thinking of moving in that direction it would probably be nice to know it doesn't always work for very complicated data types (in my example a collection of objects containing 2 strings and 2 arrays - only returns a collection of 1 string). Granted, it does work 99% of the time, but not always.

Comment: There are definitely some issues with the XMLDecoder. We've done several different integrations with .NET web service backends and usually run into at least one issue that we needed to work around.